# New to Linux, having problems installing Ubuntu 12.04 to brand new laptop

Tags: 12.04, installation, dual-boot, partitioning

I've been trying to install Ubuntu 12.04 on my new laptop (currently a Windows 7 OS) with a LiveCD, using 64-bit (Since the computer is only a few days old, and if it's newer than 2010, the 64-bit version is the one I should be using, correct?) and it boots to the installation just fine, but during installation it skips the step that gives me the option to dual boot with my current OS (something I would like to be able to do) and takes me to the screen with partitioning. On this screen, the partitioning menu is empty and all of the buttons are greyed out. Of course, if I press "install now" it gives me the error message,

> No root file system defined. Please correct this from the partitioning menu.

So, I would like to know how to install Ubuntu to dual-boot, and I'd like to know how to solve this partitioning issue. Even though my computer doesn't run on Windows 8, it is still new, so would I be able to/should I install using wubi?
 As I said, I'm new to Linux and Ubuntu, so I apologize for my inexperience.

Comment: Please run the [Boot Info Script](http://sourceforge.net/projects/bootinfoscript/) from a Linux live CD and post the `RESULTS.txt` file that it produces to a pastebin site, such as [the Ubuntu pastebin.](http://paste.ubuntu.com/) Post the URL to your pastebinned document here.

Comment: There may be two reasons for these. **(1)** The computer has 4 primary partitions, the maximum it can have. In this case, you have to delete at least one primary partition and create an extended partition, that can contain many logical partitions. **(2)** The computer has a small SSD to assist the HDD using **intel smart response**. Ubuntu does not understand this properly.

Answer (score 1):

> On this screen, the partitioning menu is empty and all of the buttons are greyed out. Of course, if I press "install now" it gives me the error message, (...)

This is because first you have to select on the **partitioning menu** field where exactly you want to have partitions on your disk. So just click on some place on it (for example click words "free space") and then your greyed buttons will be able to be pressed.

[image]

What architecture of Linux system you need depends on your processor architecture, no matter when you bought it. Remember you are able to install and run 32-bit systems on a 64-bit CPU, but not vice versa.

Answer (score 0):

I would say you may have something wrong with disc?
I would download a fresh copy of 12.04 and burn a new ISO image disc (you'll probably have to download 3rd party software, even though Win 7 should be able to burn ISO image)
 I'm real new Ubuntu/Linux user and was pretty worried I would lose information or reformat drive accidentally but everything went incredibly easy and automatic
You could try booting direct from disc to make sure it works without installing (you do have that option available?)